# Git pushes not visible in repository

Tags: macos, git

After several massive failures at work I've decided we should have some sort of version control at work. I picked git.

- Installed git
- Created a repository with admin account

  - `cd /path/to/hd/`
  - `cd mkdir test.git`
  - `cd test.git` to make sure it isn't a bare repository
  - `git init`
  - `touch README.txt` to create a text file
- Cloned the repository `git clone /Volumes/Data/git/test/`
- Created a branch `git checkout -b mybranch`
- Made modifications to the readme file
- Pushed branch `git push origin mybranch`
- Moved back to master `git checkout master`
- Deleted branch `git branch -d mybranch`

Everything appears to work so far. So I look up the files on the server, but they remain unchanged. When I open `test.git` with [GitX](http://gitx.frim.nl/), the commits are present. The changes are there. But the actual files haven't changed.

What am I doing wrong?

PS. I followed this guide: http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/

Comment: I assume you create `test.git` as a bare repo?  (i.e. you did `git init --bare`)  If so, it has no working directory, so you will not see committed files there.

Comment: Did you update the working copy at upstream server? Sounds like not. The origin git is just a normal git repo, not any different from your clone, any checked out files do not magically get changes without merge/pull/rebase.

Answer (score 1):

What your seeing is the result of pushing to a repository with a working copy.  When you push to a repo with a working copy there are two possible results.

- If the branch currently checked out is the branch you're trying to update the push will fail.
- Otherwise, the branch your pushing to will be updated, but the working copy will not change because a different branch was updated.

What you now have on the server is probably something like this:

```
A <- master
|
B <- mybranch
```

Where master is checked out, and since you haven't changed master nothing went wrong when you pushed to the server.

For this reason when you create a repository that you're going to use as a remote you almost never want it to have a working copy (i.e. actual checked out files).  You want to create a bare repository, and also probably want it to be shared, like this:

```
 git init --bare --shared=true
```

The `shared` option can also be a number of other settings, see `git help init` for options.

I think the work flow you're looking for is something along the lines of

- On Server

  - `git init --bare --shared=true`
- On your machine

  - `git clone /path/to/remote`
  - `git checkout -t -b mybranch`
  - [do work, commit on mybranch]
  - Either
  - `git checkout master && git merge mybranch && git push origin master` Updates master on the remote
  - `git push origin mybranch` Create the branch `mybranch` on the remote without updating master.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but maybe `git commit` before pushes will help?